# Jira 7.+ database schema changes

Tags: mysql, schema, jira

Does anyone know if MySQL database schema changed from Jira version 6.x to 7.x?

I asked Atlassian support, but had no definitive answer. They proposed to install clean version of Jira 7 and compare tables with version 6.

Answer (score 1):

Well, since no one replied, I've downloaded and installed Jira7 and compaired it with Jira6.  Here are my observations (**in my environment**).

--Tables counts:
jira6 - 267
jira7 - 239

-- bunch of AO.* tables were removed (this is where your count could be different)

-- these tables were added
board
boardproject
deadletter
tempattachmentsmonitor

-- these tables have added/changed index
cwd_user
jiraaction
jiraissue

In all, mostly, what I saw is addition of CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin in every "create table" statement

Answer (score 0):

I have asked the same thing , and they dont have one available.

Answer (score 0):

Database schemas are available in PDF format here:

https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/jira-platform/jira-architecture/database-schema

Atlassian says -

> The PDFs below show the database schema for JIRA 6.1 EAP 3 (m03) and JIRA 5.1.2.

[jira70_schema.pdf](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/files/4227160/45525621/1/1486695169318/jira70_schema.pdf)

[JIRA61_db_schema.pdf](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/files/4227160/22184109/1/1373928653214/JIRA61_db_schema.pdf)

[JIRA_512_DBSchema.pdf](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/files/4227160/12812303/1/1344803595615/JIRA_512_DBSchema.pdf)

> The database schema is also described in WEB-INF/classes/entitydefs/entitymodel.xml in the JIRA web application. The entitymodel.xml file has an XML definition of all JIRA's database tables, table columns and their data type. Some of the relationships between tables also appear in the file.
>   Generating JIRA database schema information
>   To generate schema information for the JIRA database, e.g. the PDF above, follow the instructions below. You can generate schema information in pdf, txt and dot formats. Note, if you want to generate the schema in PDF format, you need to have Graphviz installed.
>
> Download the attached plugin:
>
> For JIRA 5:  [jira-schema-diagram-generator-plugin-1.0.jar](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/files/4227160/12812304/1/1344818298484/jira-schema-diagram-generator-plugin-1.0.jar)
>
> For JIRA 6: [jira-schema-diagram-generator-plugin-1.0.1.jar](https://developer.atlassian.com/jiradev/files/4227160/28411024/1/1402629758150/jira-schema-diagram-generator-plugin-1.0.1.jar)
>
> For JIRA 7: [jira-schema-diagram-generator-plugin-1.1.0.jar](http://jira-schema-diagram-generator-plugin-1.1.0.jar)
>
> Install the plugin in your JIRA instance by following the instructions on Managing JIRA's Plugins.
>
> Go to the JIRA administration console and navigate to System > Troubleshooting and Support > Generate Schema Diagram
>   (tick)Keyboard shortcut: g + g + start typing generate
>   Enter the tables/columns to omit from the generated schema information, if desired.
>   If you want to generate a pdf, enter the path to the Graphviz executable.
>   Click Generate Schema.
>   The 'Database Schema' page will be displayed with links to the schema file in txt, dot and pdf format.

(You could probably get the XML or txt file and compare it in a file compare program to get specific changes.)